# Aviation business administration/ management or aeronautical engineering

Tags: commercial-aviation, airline-operations

Hello im an  a & p considering continuing education in avaiation field for better opportunity, wondering if there are any suggestions on either Aviation business administration/ management or aeronautical  engineering wold be better based on salary and opportunity wise?
thank you!

Comment: I'm afraid this is either off-topic or too broad. Aviation business admin/management can be a number of different, entirely unrelated fields, and aeronautical engineering covers a wide range of job types. I'd suggest doing some research on job boards in your area to get a feel for the demand and salary ranges.

Comment: Also there doesn't appear to be a clear question.

Answer (score 3):

Both areas have good opportunities for work and good pay, the engineering side of things offering a little higher salary but still....

As in any occupation, I would seek something that you feel fulfilled in doing more than merely making a good living.  I left aerospace engineering and went into software development for that reason.  You have to spend 1/3 of your adult life working so make sure it's something you can go home at night with a sense of accomplishment and fulfillment in doing.  Don't work a job where you're miserable and living for the weekends simply because it pays a little better.

Ask yourself if you enjoy the managerial aspects of aviation or the technical aspects.  If you enjoy working on aircraft try getting a job as an A&P at an OEM and find ways to learn about becoming a manufacturing engineer.  I know several people at Boeing and Gulfstream who followed that route and it would be a good way to get into the engineering side of the business.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a valid question as it has to do with a career in aviation.

There is a right answer to this question and it's aero engineering.  You can take it anywhere (and be taken seriously) and coupled with an A&P could be attractive to major aerospace employers.  It also carries weight in non-technical roles whereas the biz degree will generally keep you in non-tech positions.

If you're going to do business get a plain ol' BS in Business Admin.  Some specialty like marketing or finance would be better but do what whatever you can for as little money as you can.  Aviation is a specialty that nobody cares about, even within the aviation community!  If you have career experience already then the degree is only going to check a box on the application.  Consider a Tier I MBA if you grow your career into a management position.  Undergrad degrees on their own, even from great schools, are sort of like highschool v2.0.

You have the advantage of work experience which makes the "name recognition" of your undergrad school less important.  I would get the most reasonably priced degree you can and focus on a science/engineering path.  The name of the school becomes more important when you consider a masters/doctoral program.

Context for the answer:
I have a BS in BizAdmin and a Tier I MBA.  I started my undergrad as a "professional flight" major and switched to the university's business school within 18mo.  I considered a transfer to the avation management major but the course list was nearly identical to the "pro flight" coursework.  Additionally, the aviation management program was under a college nobody would recognize whereas the business college is well ranked.  Price was equal.  If I could do it again I would consider a mechanical engineering path because it's more fun than business.

Food for thought.